# how can I enable jQuery foreach on my image captions?

Tags: jquery

I have this jQuery to animate some captions on an image:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.box').mouseenter(function(){
            $('.caption').stop().animate({height: "90%"});
    }); 

    $('.box').mouseleave(function(){
            $('.caption').stop().animate({height: "15%"},  2500, function() {
            });
    });
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="caption">
        <h3>One</h3>
        <p>Under</p>
    </div>
    <img src="/i/d.jpg" />
</div>
```

Works great for only one image. I do however want there to be more, but at present on mouseenter all the captions animate together.

How can I get it to work for each one individually?

Comment: Provide html code.

Comment: @Kinduser done :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$(this)` to refer to the elements relative to the event:

```
$('.box').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).find('.caption').stop().animate({height: "90%"});
}); 

$('.box').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).find('.caption').stop().animate({height: "15%"},  2500, function() {
        });
});
```